# Проблема с разделением столбца pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Столкнулся с проблемой, хочу разделить ряд по очевидному разделителю - "\".
Пример данных:

> Column = id\tlabel\tx\ty\tcluster\tweight\tweight\tweight
>
> Row = 96\taagaard a.\t-0.297\t0.2777\t4\t1186\t2322\t23

Сначала пытался через /, но там видимо что то с табуляцией и expand = True не работал, попробовал через 't' но тоже выдает ошибку.

```
prep[['Id','Label','X','Y','Cluster','Links','Total link strength','Citations']] = prep['id\tlabel\tx\ty\tcluster\tweight<Links>\tweight<Total link strength>\tweight<Citations>'].str.split('t',expand = True)
```

Answer (score 3):

Странно у вас колонка называется...

```
prep = pd.DataFrame(['96\taagaard a.\t-0.297\t0.2777\t4\t1186\t2322\t23'], columns=['id\tlabel\tx\ty\tcluster\tweight\tweight\tweight'])
prep[['Id', 'Label', 'X', 'Y', 'Cluster', 'Links', 'Total link strength', 'Citations']] = prep['id\tlabel\tx\ty\tcluster\tweight\tweight\tweight'].str.split('\t', expand=True, regex=False)
print(prep)
```

```
    id\tlabel\tx\ty\tcluster\tweight\tweight\tweight  Id       Label       X       Y Cluster Links Total link strength Citations
0  96\taagaard a.\t-0.297\t0.2777\t4\t1186\t2322\t23  96  aagaard a.  -0.297  0.2777       4  1186                2322        23
```

Comment: Благодарю! Это с vosviewer данные, перевел с txt формат в csv. Ваш способ не сработал, есть какие нибудь варианты сплит по \ сделать?

Comment: Способ сработал для приведенных вами данных. Выходит, реальные данные другие. Пока не будет реальных данных, что-то предложить сложно.

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужно разделить строку по обратному слэшу ("\") а не по знаку табуляции (хотя последнее напрашивается как очевидное), то можно попробовать сделать что-то подобное:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Col1":["id\tlabel\tx\ty\tcluster\tweight\tweight\tweight"]})
```

df:

```
                                               Col1
0  id\tlabel\tx\ty\tcluster\tweight\tweight\tweight
```

а затем:

```py
res = df["Col1"].str.encode('unicode_escape').apply(lambda x:x.split(b"\\")).explode().str.decode("unicode_escape")
```

res:

```
0          id
0      tlabel
0          tx
0          ty
0    tcluster
0     tweight
0     tweight
0     tweight
Name: Col1, dtype: object
```